# System.Xml.XmlException: The 'table' start tag on line 104 position 10 does not match the end tag of 'div'. Line 133, position 5

Tags: html, xml

i'm getting the exception error:
**System.Xml.XmlException: The 'table' start tag on line 104 position 10 does not match the end tag of 'div'. Line 133, position 5.**

The HTML code we have appears to work fine but since there is an xml error, can someone please help see if it's the xml code with the problem?  I dont' konw anything about xml - is it the $?

<xsl:variable name="AllocationAmount"><xsl:value-of select="Allocation" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="AllocationFormatted">$<xsl:value-of select="format-number($AllocationAmount, '###,##0.00')" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="AvailableBalanceAmount"><xsl:value-of select="AvailableBalance" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="AvailableBalanceFormatted">$<xsl:value-of select="format-number($AvailableBalanceAmount, '###,##0.00')" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="RequestedAmount"><xsl:value-of select="TotalRequestedAmount" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="RequestedFormatted">$<xsl:value-of select="format-number($RequestedAmount, '###,##0.00')" /></xsl:variable>

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the fragment you've posted, it's somewhere else. The posted fragment doesn't contain a `table` start tag.